# How to combine ifconfig with openssl to change MAC address

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, openssl, mac-address

I am trying to make a one-line MAC Address spoofer. However, I cannot combine ifconfig with OpenSSL.

My method of doing this is to change the MAC Address to a randomly generated MAC Address using OpenSSL. However, combining the code to change the MAC Address with the random MAC Address creator doesn't seem to work.

```
openssl rand -hex6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g;s?.$//
```

This code creates a random MAC Address

```
sudo ifconfig en0 ether xyz
```

This code sets the MAC Address to xyz

Combining these two lines did not change the MAC Address as expected.

```
sudo ifconfig en0 ether openssl rand -hex6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g;s?.$//
```

This code returns a "Invalid Argument"

I expect this to be a formatting issue, but I could not find proper formatting guides online and I am new to bash.

Comment: There are several things to consider when creating MAC addresses because the MAC address space is divided into parts for unicast/multicast/broadcast/globally unique/locally administered. See: [MAC_address#Address_details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Address_details)

Answer (score 6):

There are a bunch of problems in this code. I think the main thing you are missing is that you need `$( )` to capture the output of one command so you can use it as an argument to another command (and you generally want double-quotes around that, to avoid unexpected parsing weirdness). The way you've written it, `openssl rand -hex6` isn't treated as a command, just as three more arguments to `sudo ifconfig` (and it's the output from `sudo ifconfig` that's piped to `sed`).

You also need a space in `-hex 6`, and the end of the `sed` command is using inconsistent delimiters and is missing a close quote. Also, rather than using a capture group in the first `sed` command, you can just use `&` to get the entire matched string (i.e. `s/../&:/g`).

Here's a corrected version:

```
sudo ifconfig en0 ether "$(openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/../&:/g;s/:$//')"
```

EDIT: as @Cyrus pointed out in a comment, MAC address space is divided up into globally- vs. locally administered, and uncast vs. multicast (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Address_details)). Using a multicast address might cause trouble, so it'd really be better to force the second digit to be even. This is a bit tricky, so I'm going to duck the question of how to do it...